# merge nodes based on common property and add all properties to the initial node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In this image you can see all the properties from a node, what I want to achieve is to merge the nodes based on CUI (id) and add those properties to one initial node.

[image: In this image you can see all the properties from a node, what I want to achieve is to merge the nodes based on CUI (id) and add those properties to one initial node]

I tried

```
START first=node(*), second=node(*) 
WHERE exists (first.id) and exists (second.id) 
WITH first, second
SKIP 20000 LIMIT 20000
WHERE first.id= second.id
SET first=second;
```

but there are no changes

then I tried calling the APOC

```
match (f:Disease),(b:Disease) where f.id=b.id 
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([f,b]) yield node 
return "none";
```

which gives me an error

> ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure. Due to security
>   constraints in your web browser, the reason for the failure is not
>   available to this Neo4j Driver. Please use your browsers development
>   console to determine the root cause of the failure. Common reasons
>   include the database being unavailable, using the wrong connection URL
>   or temporary network problems. If you have enabled encryption, ensure
>   your browser is configured to trust the certificate Neo4j is
>   configured to use. WebSocket `readyState` is: 3

Can someone help with a query which merges the nodes and adds the properties so I will not lose information?

Comment: What should happen if two or more nodes having the same id have a different value for the same property? for example, there are 2 or more nodes with id=1 having different values for property 'select'.

Comment: i want the property to be added at the initial node, dont lose any data

Comment: i want the property to be added at the initial node, dont lose any data

Comment: MATCH (o:Disease),(b:Disease) WHERE o.id=b.id and o<>b and o.name_doctor<>b.name_doctor SET  o.name_doctor=o.name_doctor+", "+b.name_doctor RETURN o,b;  I tried this query,the only problem is that is not adding the property only once, I have duplicate properties in all nodes with same id, plus i want to delete the nodes and leave just one node with all properties inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, run this to create uniqueness constraint and add an index on `id` property of Disease. ***[IMPORTANT]***

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (d:Disease) ASSERT d.id IS UNIQUE
```

Then Run the following query to load the data. 
This will create the node if it's not present and set the properties. 
**If the node already exists it will append the values.**

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///ConditionConcepts.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
MERGE (disease:Disease {id: line.CUI}) 
ON CREATE SET 
    disease.name_doctor = line.name, 
    disease.relevance = line.cui_relevance, 
    disease.trials = line.trials_count, 
    disease.search = line.search_frequency, 
    disease.select = line.select_frequency
ON MATCH SET
    disease.name_doctor = disease.name_doctor+", "+line.name, 
    disease.relevance = disease.relevance+", "+line.cui_relevance, 
    disease.trials = disease.trials+", "+line.trials_count, 
    disease.search = disease.search+", "+line.search_frequency, 
    disease.select = disease.select+", "+line.select_frequency
```

Comment: When i run the query i get this error : Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'E': expected 'a/A' (line 10, column 5 (offset: 388))
"ON MERGE SET", then i changed in set only and it works, the only problem is that it will duplicate the first value, so for example if i need to merge Cancer and Colon Cancer then the node result is Cancer, Cancer, Colon Cancer. Do you know why did i get that error?

Comment: My Mistake, I used MERGE instead of MATCH on line 10. Changed it please check

Comment: you are amazing! thank you very much! everything works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I can show you an easier example of what I want [image: this is the initial situation, all id are the same]

after I apply the following query

```
MATCH (o:Disease),(b:Disease) 
WHERE o.id=b.id and o<>b and o.name_doctor<>b.name_doctor 
SET o.name_doctor=o.name_doctor+", "+b.name_doctor 
RETURN o,b;
```

I will have this result

[image: after applying the query]

but this is not what I want, in the end, I need to have one node which will have the properties of the others, something like this [image: ideal situation].

maybe there is a way of doing this at creation, I have to load a CSV file in order to have the data, if I use merge (instead of creating) or constraint, I will lose properties.

I need to find a way to create the nodes without losing any data.

Comment: It's possible to do what you are asking on the existing database, but I am not clear what should happen to other existing properties? Like you are joining the name of the doctor by appending with the existing name but not clear what should happen with the values of other properties (like 'select').  So my question is what should be the value of 'select' for the merged node if 3 nodes have values for ex 2,3,2.

Comment: It will be easier if you do this at the time of loading Data from CSV.

Comment: the other existing proprieties should be added with a coma at the initial node, or at all nodes with the same id but after I have to delete the nodes which are the same. so, for example, the select would be beaded with a coma to the other initial node property select. Same as i showed with the name_doctor, they are added with a coma to the initial node but at the end i need to have one node with all properties

Comment: you say it can be done at creation, this is the query which i use to load the nodes: USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///ConditionConcepts.csv' AS line
FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
  WITH DISTINCT line

  MERGE (disease:Disease {id: line.`CUI`})
  SET disease.name_doctor = line.`name`,
      disease.relevance = line.`cui_relevance`,
      disease.trials = line.`trials_count`,
      disease.search = line.`search_frequency`,
      disease.select = line.`select_frequency`
;
my approach is: instead of create

Comment: with this query, I lose the properties of the nodes which have the same id. my approach is: instead of MERGE I use CREATE so then I will have duplicate nodes but I will not lose properties, I was thinking it will be easier to merge the nodes with the same id and merge the properties to one node.  how can I modify the query in such a way that it will create a node with an id and all the properties from other nodes with the same id will be added?